# Как установить textSize в TextView как в actionBar

Tags: android, android-textview

Как можно установить атрибут textSize в TextView ( в xml-файле) такой же как в actionBar ? Ну т.е. что бы размер шрифта в actionBar и TextView был одинаковый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: в стилях actionBar-a titleTextStyle установить такой же размер как и в TextView ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте для указания размера текста в вашем `TextView` атрибуты из системных стилей:

`TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title` - размер для заголовков в экшенбаре (он соответствует системному размеру `TextAppearance.Medium`)

`TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle` - размер для подзаголовков в экшенбаре (он соответствует системному размеру `TextAppearance.Small`)

Узнать значения, установленные для системных виджетов, вы можете из исходников Android.
Так, например, все значения системных атрибутов для телефонов [находятся в файле res/values/styles.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) системного пакета framework-res.apk

Comment: установил TextAppearance.Medium но по-моему текст выглядит не идентично?  или так не получится? и имеет разница что я устанавливаю его в Button, а не в TextView

Comment: В каком плане не идентично, глиф другой ? Для размера текста не важно в какой виджет он установлен, размер будет одинаков, но на отображение могут влиять другие атрибуты, установленные для конкретного виджета.

Comment: Добавил картинку! А что может влиять? на пример, тема установленная для тулбара?
Как мне достичь  "одинаковости" шрифтов?

Comment: Здесь я указал для стоковой темы. Для других тем могут быть другие значения, кроме того значения могут быть изменены в стилях самого приложения. Что касается тулбара, то у него ваша разметка, вы ее сами создали. Смотрите, какой вы указали  размер для того `TextView`, что вас интересует.

Comment: не не, я не про TextView, с ним понятно, там я устанавливаю размер, я про надпись "Изучение" -  в тулбаре и надпись "Начать" в кнопке

Comment: Я про это и говорю. Макет (разметку) для тулбара с надписью "Изучение" и цифрами "1 из 6" вы создали сами, разве нет?

Comment: есть ньюанс, кнопка и тулбар который я показываю находяться в разных  активити, а TextView "1 из 6" в разметке активити нету , оно находиться в разметке menu.xml